# Trying to do a looped search for keywords with imacros

Tags: loops, imacros, keyword-search

I have a csv file with 128 different keywords (1 column, 128 rows) that I am trying to search for on my current page, and if it locates one of them to continue with a very simple task, else prompt me saying none of the keywords were found.

The goal is to have something like the following:

```
SET !DATASOURCE ...                            'already have this part working
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
{{!LOOP}} = 1
if TAG POS=1 TYPE=* ATTR=TXT:{{!COL1}} = true   'not actual code from here down 
move to next step
elseif {{!LOOP}} +1 = 129
PROMPT "No keyword was found"
END                                             'killing the script
else 
loop++                                          'loop and search for next keyword
```

If it matters, the keywords are actually IP addresses with the final block missing IE. "192.168.0."  Not sure if it would affect formatting or not. I'm sure there's a better way to do it with search. I'm just looking for a 0 or 1 (yes or no response) if a keyword is present and then continue following links if found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do conditionals such as if-then you will need to use a scripting language[[1]](http://wiki.imacros.net/FAQ#Q:_Are_there_conditional_statements_like_if..._then...else_in_the_iMacros_macro_language.3F).  I have provided a Javascript example below that follows your pseudocode.

```
var datasource, macro, retcode, numberOfLinesInDatasource, aTagWasFound;

datasource = "somedatasource";
numberOfLinesInDatasource = 128;
aTagWasFound = false;

macro = "CODE:";
// change link to a different website
macro += "URL GOTO=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467549/trying-to-do-a-looped-search-for-keywords-with-imacros\n";
retcode = iimPlay(macro);

// loop through all lines in datasource
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfLinesInDatasource; i++)
{
  // get the datasource value at this line
    macro = "CODE:";
    macro += "SET DATASOURCE " + datasource + "\n";
    macro += "SET DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1\n";
    macro += "SET DATASOURCE_LINE " + i + "\n";
    macro += "ADD !EXTRACT {{!COL1}}\n";
    retcode = iimPlay(macro);
    keyword = iimGetLastExtract();

    // search for this keyword
    macro = "CODE:";
    macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=* ATTR=TXT:" + keyword + "\n";
    retcode = iimPlay(macro);

    // if retcode is 1 then the tag was found move on to next step
    if (retcode === 1){
        // move on to next step
        aTagWasFound = true;
        break;
    }
    // tag not found try the next value
}

if (!aTagWasFound)
{
    alert("No keyword found");
} else 
{
    alert("Tag Found");
}
```

Comment: see the next answer for my reply, you can't add code efficiently in comments.